# Customize push notification sound and icon for blackberry cascades 10

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have used the pushcollector example from blackberry code from github to integrate push notification, I'm receiving notification in my device but with default sound and bell icon. I need to change the default bell icon and sound with the ones that I provide. My device is Dev Alpha B and version is 10.2.1.3061

This is my pushnotfication handler code but it doesnt set the sound or icon. Any help is appreciated

```
void ApplicationUI::pushNotificationHandler(bb::network::PushPayload &pushPayload)
{
    qDebug() << "Received push pushNotificationHandler";

    PushHistoryItem pushHistoryItem(pushPayload.id());

    if (m_pushNotificationService.checkForDuplicatePush(pushHistoryItem)) {
        qWarning() << QString("Duplicate push was found with ID: %0.").arg(pushPayload.id());

        return;
    }

    Push push(pushPayload);
    push.setSeqNum(m_pushNotificationService.savePush(push));

    Notification *notification = new Notification(NOTIFICATION_PREFIX + QString::number(push.seqNum()),this);
    notification->setTitle("Yo");


    PlatformInfo pkinfo;
            QString osVersion=pkinfo.osVersion();
            qDebug() <<"OS full:"<<osVersion;
            osVersion.resize(4);
            qDebug() <<"OS:"<<osVersion;
            float versionValue=10.2;

           if(osVersion.toFloat()>=versionValue)
           {
               qDebug() <<"Notification set:";
               notification->setIconUrl(QUrl("file://" + QDir::currentPath() + "/app/native/assets/Images/customIcon.png"));
               notification->setSoundUrl(QUrl("file://" + QDir::currentPath() + "/app/native/assets/Sounds/customSound.mp3"));
           }
           else
           {
               qDebug() <<"Notification unset OS version is:"<<osVersion.toFloat();
           }

    notification->setBody(QString("New %0 push received").arg(push.fileExtension()));

    InvokeRequest invokeRequest;
    invokeRequest.setTarget(INVOKE_TARGET_KEY_OPEN);
    invokeRequest.setAction(BB_OPEN_INVOCATION_ACTION);
    invokeRequest.setMimeType("text/plain");
    invokeRequest.setData(QByteArray::number(push.seqNum()));
    notification->setInvokeRequest(invokeRequest);
    notification->notify();

    m_model->insert(push.toMap());
    if (pushPayload.isAckRequired()) {
        m_pushNotificationService.acceptPush(pushPayload.id());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify them as **public** assets in bar-descriptor.xml and then use public urls instead of private.

Best way - create separate folder for public assets

**bar-descriptor.xml**

```
<asset path="assets">assets</asset>
<asset path="public" public="true">.</asset>
```

**C++**

```
notification->setIconUrl(QUrl("file://" + QDir::currentPath() + "/app/public/Images/customIcon.png"));
notification->setSoundUrl(QUrl("file://" + QDir::currentPath() + "/app/public/Sounds/customSound.mp3"));
```